# Calling Wait on a ManualReset event, that has already triggered a Wait call,

Tags: c#

If you have a thread waiting on a manual reset event, and you set the event, which allows the thread to continue, what happens if you call wait again without another set call?

Comment: [Unless you reset the handle, it stays in the signaled state and any subsequent calls will not block on `.WaitOne();` until the handle's state is not longer signaled.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=net-5.0#examples)

Comment: Try it and see.  That or see Demi’s comment

Comment: @DekuDesu  - can you respond as an answer so I can mark it as such? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ManualResetEvent` can either be in a signaled or unsignaled state.

When you signal the event(handle) you allow any waiting threads to continue execution.

[Because this is a *manual* wait handle, it remains in the signaled state until you tell it to reset.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=net-5.0#examples)

While in a signaled state the handle will allow any executing threads checking it's status with `.WaitOne()` to continue without blocking their execution.

When you reset the event *manually* the handle will force any subsequent calls to `.WaitOne()` to block execution of those threads.

You can think of a `ManualResetEvent` as a water faucet. When you turn the faucet on, water flows through effortlessly. Water will continue to flow as long as the faucet is on. When you manually turn off the faucet the water stops flowing.

This is different from an `AutoResetEvent` where it's more akin to a turnstile at a train station. Only one person can walk through at once, and every time they do, the turnstile locks behind them to prevent additional people. The turnstile will prevent additional people so long as they haven't swiped their card or paid.